# Can I make a SharePoint Image Web Part clickable to link to another page

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

The Image Web Part doesn't seem to have an href attribute that I can set.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 7):

Does it have to be an Image Web Part? If not I would simply use a [Content Editor Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA100240461033.aspx) and paste the required HTML there.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="urlToImage" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

what if it have to? 
users need to have an opportunity to change the link and the image themselves and not to disturb an administrator.